# okhttp:Chinese characters garbled

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

```
public class CustomInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        final Request request = chain.request();
        final String urlStr = request.url().toString();
        final Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();

            if (request.body() != null && request.body() instanceof FormBody) {
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                final RequestBody newBody = RequestBody.create(mediaType, content);

                final Request newRequest = builder.url(urlStr)
                        .header("User-Agent", ApiUtils.getUserAgent())
                        .header("Content-Type", oldBody.contentType().toString())
                        .header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(content.length()))
                        .method(request.method(), newBody)
                        .build();


                //
                final Response response = chain.proceed(newRequest);
                final ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                final Headers headers = response.headers();
                BufferedSource source = responseBody.source();
                source.request(Long.MAX_VALUE); // Buffer the entire body.
                Buffer buffer = source.buffer();
                Charset charset = UTF8;
                MediaType contentType = responseBody.contentType();
                String realResult;
                try {
                    if (contentType != null) {
                        charset = contentType.charset(UTF8);
                    }
                    final String result = buffer.clone().readString(charset);//garbled
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.v(e.getMessage());
                    return response;
                }
                return response.newBuilder()
                        .body(ResponseBody.create(contentType != null ? contentType : MediaType.parse(oldBody.contentType().toString()),
                                realResult.getBytes()))
                        .build();
            }
    }

}
```

---

### `final String result = buffer.clone().readString(charset);` this is garbled, and I have tried `GBK` or `GBK2312`, it also is garbled. I used retrofit and custom converters: `String result= responseBody.string();`, this is good, but it still garbled in interceptor.

I has used responseBody.string() in my interceptor,but it also is garbled.
 @iagreen

Comment: if `responseBody.string()` is working for you in another place, why aren't you using that in your interceptor?

Comment: I has used responseBody.string() in my interceptor,but it also is garbled.